# Schrieffer-Wolff transformation for interacting bosons on a lattice

Tags: second-quantization, non-linear-systems

I have the following Hamiltonian for bosons in a lattice model with on-site interactions

$$H = H_0 + gV,$$

$$H_0=\sum_{n=1}^3 \left[ \omega_0 a_n^\dagger a_n + \Omega \right( a_n^\dagger a_{n+1} + a_{n+1}^\dagger a_n \left)\right],$$

$$V= \sum_{n=1}^3 a_n^\dagger a_n^\dagger a_n a_n.$$

I want to do a Schrieffer-Wolff transformation by imposing $[H_0,S]=V$, such that

$$e^{gS}He^{-gS} = H_0 + \frac{g^2}{2} [S,V] + \mathcal{O}(g^3).$$

How can I find $S$? I'm struggling to approach this in a more intelligent way than just guessing.